# VHDL: a+b+carry_in creates two adders instead of using carry in in the existing adder

Tags: vhdl, quartus-ii

I want to add A, B and the carry in. This should be done using only one big adder. But when I look at the circuit generated, there is an extra adder for the carry in. How can I solve this problem?

Picture:

[image]

Code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity adder is
    port(
        a, b : in unsigned(3 downto 0);
        result : out unsigned(3 downto 0);
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        cin : in integer
    );
end entity;
architecture behavioral of adder is
    signal a_r, b_r, result_r : unsigned(3 downto 0);
    signal cin_r : integer;
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            a_r <= a;
            b_r <= b;
            cin_r <= cin;
            result_r <= a_r + b_r + to_unsigned(cin_r, 4);
        end if;
        result <= result_r;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

Comment: speculation here, so not an answer. Cin is an integer, you may need to extract bit 4 external to your adder process and forward the single bit. But, it looks like it has synthesised what you have asked for, which is two adders, two plus signs in the expression. What width does the function to_unsigned expand up to? If you have a specific FPGA vendor in mind, then they will provide libraries from which you can directly generate full adders. The generic logic you are generating in this step may be synthesised correctly by a vendor's software.

Comment: What does the technology map output look like. RTL is only half the story - even in Verilog you can end up with the same "two adders" in RTL, but there is only one in the technology map. But either way, your signals seem to be all the wrong size as the others have pointed out,

Comment: cin, cin_r S.B. std_logic (1 bit), `result_r <= a_r + b_r + ("" & cin_r);` Converts cin_r to unsigned, length 1.

Comment: You have removed the problem from your question. The good news is it can be recovered from the edit history. You could show your modifications and results in a separate answer. It might even get up votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are `cin` and `cin_r` of type `integer`? You can see in the Altera RTL view that it's trying to synthesize a 32-bit wide signal!

Typically, a VHDL adder would take two `unsigned` or `signed` inputs of appropriate width and the `cin` input of type `std_logic` or similar one-bit-wide signal. Try changing the two `integer`s into `std_logic`s and seeing if the `result_r <= a_r + b_r + ("" & cin_r);` (suggested by user8352) can correctly infer an adder with carry-in.

Also, your adder does not appear to correctly handle overflow/carry.

Comment: When changing cin and cin_r to STD_LOGIC I get the following error: Error (10476): VHDL error at adder.vhd(21): type of identifier "cin_r" does not agree with its usage as "natural" type

Comment: I don't have any VHDL tools handy, but I changed the form to user8352's comment suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers so far use two adders.  If you want to use a single adder you need to incorporate the carry into the numbers being passed to the adder. Add a new low-order bit. For one input, set it to 1. For the other input, set it to carry-in. Now you can do the operation with a single adder.

The following example should put you on the right path.  You'll have to adapt it for your application.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder is
    port(
        a, b     : in   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        sum      : out  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        carry_in : in   std_logic;
        carry_out: out  std_logic);
end entity;

architecture behavioral of adder is

    signal sum6bit : std_logic_vector (5 downto 0);

begin

    sum6bit <= std_logic_vector(unsigned('0' & a & '1') + 
                                unsigned('0' & b & carry_in)); 
    carry_out <= sum6bit(5);
    sum <= sum6bit(4 downto 1);

end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you have to change `cin` and `cin_r` to STD_LOGIC.
The line

```
result_r <= a_r + b_r + to_unsigned(cin_r, 4);
```

becomes

```
result_r <= a_r + b_r + ("" & cin_r);
```

The new code is:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
entity adder is
    port(
        a, b : in unsigned(3 downto 0);
        result : out unsigned(3 downto 0);
        clk, cin : in STD_LOGIC
    );
end entity;
architecture behavioral of adder is
    signal a_r, b_r, result_r : unsigned(3 downto 0);
    signal cin_r : STD_LOGIC;
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            a_r <= a;
            b_r <= b;
            cin_r <= cin;
            result_r <= a_r + b_r + ("" & cin_r);
        end if;
        result <= result_r;
    end process;
end behavioral;
```

Answer (score 0):

All current answers are bad design. a b and c should all be either integers or unsigneds. Correctly defining the ranges will solve the problem.

Either cin and cin_r become

```
unsigned(0 downto 0)
```

and a and b stay as they are now or you put

```
a : natural range 0 to 7
b : natural range 0 to 7
a_r : natural range 0 to 7
b_r : natural range 0 to 7
cin : natural range 0 to 1
cin_r : natural range 0 to 1
```